# Two Divs will not sit behind my lightbox

Tags: css, lightbox

so I am having issues with a couple of divs that sit on top of a image slider one of which sits there nicely while when you hover over it another div then slides over it. So, I have a lightbox on there which fades the background down to 90% black but these two divs jus sit high and mighty above everything despite the z-index set quite low...

```
    <style>
        #ecardhover { 
        background: red;
        border: thin solid #dcdcdc; 
        width:490px; 
        height:260px; 
        display:none; 
        position:absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 30px;
}

        #trigger {
        float: left;   
        background-color: #eee;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 30px; 
        padding-bottom: 20px; 
        width: 450px; 
        margin-top: -68px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        height: 210px; 
        z-index: 111111; 
        position: relative;

}
        </style>
```

Is it to do with the positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cured the problem by adjusting all the z-index prperties to 00001 and altering the overlay to 999999 and overrode the entirety of the the divs.